# Only forward every X argument

Tags: bash

I am using ImageMagick's montage to create a preview of pictures; e. g.

```
montage *.jpg output.jpg
```

However, *.jpg are lots of files; and many are similar, e.g.

```
a.jpg b.jpg c.jpg d.jpg 01.jpg
```

Can I somehow only pass every Xth file to montage?

For example every second file:

```
a.jpg c.jpg 01.jpg
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store all the files in an array. Then loop over the array and pick alternate elements as shown below:

```
all=( *.jpg )
for (( i=0; i<${#all[@]}; i+=2 )); do
    everyOther+=( "${all[$i]}" )
done    
montage "${everyOther[@]}" output.jpg
```